# To delete a shared or public snapshot, you must use the log into the AWS account that owns the snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created a test PostgreSQL instance in AWS and deleted the instance but public snapshots are growing more.

when I'm trying to delete those, it is saying 'To delete a shared or public snapshot, you must use the log into the AWS account that owns the snapshot.'

I followed

```
To delete a DB snapshot

* Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon RDS console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/.

* In the navigation pane, choose Snapshots.

* Choose the DB snapshot that you want to delete.

* For Actions, choose Delete Snapshot.

* Choose Delete on the confirmation page.
```

Suggest me the way or what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Image

[image: Public Snapshot]

Comment: What do you mean by "public snapshots are growing more"? Where are these Snapshots appearing? If you are in the Amazon RDS 'Snapshots' console, is it set to `Owned by Me` or `All Public Snapshots`? Can you provide a picture?

Comment: Thank you @john and attached screenshot maybe this will help.

Answer (score 5):

**Public Snapshots** are snapshots created by *other people* that are being shared to everybody on AWS.

They are not *your* snapshots and they do not contain *your* data. Note the second column, which shows the name of the database. Those names should be unfamiliar to you, since they are other people's snapshots, not yours.

I can see the same listing as you.

**Bottom line:** Don't worry. They're not yours, they're not costing you money and your data is not being exposed (unless you specifically make a Snapshot public).